# Put icon for wireless on desktop

Tags: wireless

I am running Ubuntu 10.0.4 I am disabling the gnome top panel, but want to put a icon on the desktop to connect to wireless. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can only run one instance of `nm-applet --sm-disable` so if you want to call it manually I suppose that you have to delete it from the list of the Applications that run at the startup and call it once from a Terminal.